# Dynamic table name or query for Cassandra connector / Dynamic sink of Flink job

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My Flink job needs to write to different Cassandra tables for different time. For this scenario, either dynamic table name or dynamic query for Cassandra connector, or dynamic sink for the Flink job works for me.

There is a similar question 3 years ago, and the answer is no. ([Dynamic Table name in Cassandra Pojo Sink Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183039/dynamic-table-name-in-cassandra-pojo-sink-flink#new-answer?newreg=da6ac7bbee614266a22c6b797c44522c)) I am wondering if there is any update.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: didn't find any related ticket in flink jira tasks using keywords like "dynamic table name Cassandra" "dynamic query Cassandra"...(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3311?jql=project%20%3D%20FLINK%20AND%20text%20~%20%22dynamic%20query%20cassandra%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I implemented my own Cassandra sink, which generates different query when sending the data to Cassandra. I referred to the existing CassandraRowSink in Flink. It works for this use case.